# [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed expo]

Tags: react-native

This is the fetch function.

```
const fetchApi = async () => {

        const response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api")
        const data = await response.json();
        const gd = data.map(e => {
            return {
                value: parseFloat(e.total),
                label: determine_sub_type(e.subs_type),
                color: dtermineColor(e.subs_type),
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use your **IP Address** of your computer.

e.g : `http://192.168.1.100:8000/api` with https portocol